# Disable Visual C++ boost warning

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, visual-studio-2013, compiler-warnings

I get warnings about boost-serialize in Visual Studio 2013.

```
boost/archive/basic_binary_iprimitive.hpp(152) : while compiling class template member function 'void boost::archive::basic_binary_iprimitive<Archive,Elem,Tr>::load_binary(void *,size_t)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::naked_binary_iarchive,
1>              Elem=char,
1>              Tr=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
...
```

How can I disable them?

Comment: You're missing part of the error.  As far as how to disable it, the normal methods of suppressing warnings should work.

Comment: `#pragma warning( disable : <warning_number> )`

Comment: It works. Thank you. Can I do it in project settings instead of pragma?

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to disable the specific warning:

1. use the directive `#pragma warning( disable : warning number)` as the comments say.
2. On the Advanced property page of the project's Property Pages, modify the Disable Specific Warnings property.
   [image]